# NSUrlConnection in multiple NSOperation instances in a NSOperationQueue

Tags: objective-c, request, nsurlconnection, synchronous, nsoperationqueue

The following code adds multiple NSOperation instances in an NSOperationQueue. The Operation just takes the contents of a url. I'm providing the php code too...

Given the following code...

```
-(void)requestResponse {

    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.someurl.gr/test.php"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:40.0];

    NSDate *dd = [NSDate date];

    NSURLResponse *resp;
    NSData *returnedData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&resp error:NULL];

    NSString *ss = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];

    NSLog(@"%@ - %.2f",ss , -[dd timeIntervalSinceNow]);

}


-(NSOperation*)task {
    NSInvocationOperation* theOp = [[[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(requestResponse) object:nil] autorelease];
    return theOp;
}


-(IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender {

    NSOperationQueue *opq = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [opq setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:40];

    for(int i=0; i<15;i++) {
        [opq addOperation:[self task]];
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0]; // here is the issue!
    }

    [opq release];
}
```

The contents of the test.php witch -requestResponse calls:

```
<?php
    echo "Through!";
    for($i=0;$i<1000000;$i++) { // don't return too soon
    }
?>
```

The issue is that when i use `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0]` to create a delay before each NSOperation addition in the queue, all requests take about the same time to complete. If I comment this line most requests take considerably **increasingly** more and more time to complete. The question is why?

I have tested the url from command line (using curl) and the requests take the same time to complete for any number of simultaneous calls to the php, so the issue is not server side.

Here is the output using localhost as server **with sleepForTimeInterval disabled**

```
[s] Through! - 0.22
[s] Through! - 0.23
[s] Through! - 0.25
[s] Through! - 0.26
[s] Through! - 0.26
[s] Through! - 0.28
[s] Through! - 0.43
[s] Through! - 0.46
[s] Through! - 0.49
[s] Through! - 0.50
[s] Through! - 0.52
[s] Through! - 0.51
[s] Through! - 0.60
[s] Through! - 0.62
[s] Through! - 0.63
```

// of course the differences is much more higher (from 7 to 20 secs!) with a php doing some real work.

and with **sleepForTimeInterval enabled**

```
[s] Through! - 0.23
[s] Through! - 0.09
[s] Through! - 0.09
[s] Through! - 0.09
[s] Through! - 0.09
[s] Through! - 0.09
[s] Through! - 0.08
[s] Through! - 0.09
[s] Through! - 0.09
[s] Through! - 0.08
[s] Through! - 0.09
[s] Through! - 0.09
[s] Through! - 0.09
[s] Through! - 0.09
[s] Through! - 0.09
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have **sleepForTimeInterval** enabled it pauses for longer then the NSOperation takes to complete. Therefore, you really only have one concurrent operation happening at a time.

When you have **sleepForTimeInterval** disabled, you are presenting NSOperationQueue with multiple parallel operations to complete.

What do you have `[NSoperationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount]` set to? I'd ensure its set to 15 to allow all operations complete in parallel. I'm thinking that perhaps the operations are queuing at the moment and thus not all running in parallel.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The `maxConcurrentOperationCount` is set to 40! So this isn't the problem. I have implemented a method `-(void)requestResponseUsingCurl` that uses **NSTask** and **curl** command line utility to do the work and it works just fine! All operations run concurrently without additional delays. The issue is in `NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest` and actually even in `[NSString stringWithContentsOfUrl:]` that I have also tried and had the same problem. It's pretty strange, but somethings going on with the Class being used (behind the scene) to get url contents.

Comment: Cool, I'll vote down my answer then! Edit: just realised you can't vote down your own answer!

Comment: I wonder is there some property somewhere that is not set to nonatomic, and therefore there are queues building up on object locks?

Comment: xm very nice thought but no, at least as far as I can say. The code is exactly the posted one.

Comment: Just a note: I've posted a version that uses NSURLConnection for consistency. If you use `[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:@"http://www.someurl.gr/test.php"]` in `-(void)requestResponse` you'll get the exact same results.

Comment: It's a strange one. Something, somewhere must be queuing!

Comment: Out of interest. Is this on OSX or iOS?

Comment: It is on OSX. I will try it with a CGI other than php, in case there is some kind of conflict between php and URLConnection...

Comment: Good idea. Maybe its something to do with persistent connection handling on URLConnection or something. But if so, I'd expect to see that when you go sequential as well.